# How to get a minimum value from a vector with (value > 0)

Tags: c++, vector, minimum

I'm trying to reduce by some value all the elements of a vector that are not or less than 0.

I haven't really tried anything because I just can't get around with this, but I Need, for example, from a `vector{1, 2, 3, 0, -1}` the value `vector[0]`
I don't want to sort or remove any value, I need the vector to keep its "structure".

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> R;
    //I'm sorry I can't provide any code, I can't get around with this
}
```

I expect for example: from vectors

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -1}
B = {53, 36, 205, -8, -45, -93}
```

to get:

```
A[0]
B[1]
```

(Those are just random vectors to make some examples)

Comment: This problem would be way easier if you could first sort your vectors.

Comment: And then remove all non-positive values.

Comment: If only there were some `std::sort` or `std::remove_if` functions... Darn!

Comment: Why do you want to sort it??

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it, but I don't really want to change the structure of my vector, if it it (4,2,3,0) it needs to stay (4,2,3,0)

Comment: Or create two pointers one starting from the begining, the other from the end of the vector. Compare both the values sort the smallest one non negative and keep going until the end aka the center of the vector (storing and comparing each time the smallest found one) Hope I was clear... (More efficient than sorting and then go throught the vec)

Comment: Well, at least your title is clear. If you haven't gotten to it, then ask yourself how you'd find the minimum without any further restriction. Just the minimum in a vector. Then ponder how to shoehorn the extra condition in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom accumulation like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits> //std::numeric_limits
#include <numeric> //std::accumulate
#include <iterator> //std::begin, std::end

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> R{1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -1};

    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(R), std::end(R), std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), 
      [](int a, int b){if (b > 0) return std::min(a, b); return a;});
}
```

It returns the max for an integer if there are no strictly positive element in the vector.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! copy/paste forbidden when the clipboard contains "#include" at work. Crazy stupid...

Comment: I was just so impressed how one single line needs 4 includes from the standard library so I had to suggest the edit. (5 if you count iostream) haha

Comment: FWIW `std::begin` and `std::end` don't need to have `iterator` included. all of the container includes (<array>, <deque>, <forward_list>, <list>, <map>, <regex>, <set>, <span>, <string>, <string_view>, <unordered_map>, <unordered_set>, and <vector>) are guaranteed to have it included.  Rule of thumb: if you have a container included you get begin and end for free.

Answer (score 2):

This is a use case for the rather unknown [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
int smallest_positive(std::vector<int> v)
{
    std::sort(begin(v), end(v));
    return *std::lower_bound(begin(v), end(v), 0);
}
```

---

```
std::sort(begin(v), end(v));
```

This sorts a *copy* of the input vector. For simple cases, this is the best effort/perf you can get ;)

---

> [`std::lower_bound`] returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [*first*, *last*) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) *value*, or last if no such element is found.

```
std::lower_bound(begin(v), end(v), 1);
```

This scans the sorted `v` for the first element that is not negative (not less than 1) and returns an iterator to it. Beware, it returns an invalid iterator if no element of `v` is positive. I'll let you fix that ;)

Comment: @PlayLikeMe10YT Did you read the last two sentences before you get an F-?

Comment: and please add that #include <algorithm> (I'm just a newbie but I didn't know I needed that, it could be helpful for other people)

Comment: What is the F-?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher the vector is passed by value to that function.

Comment: Still, worse complexity, memory allocated... Should I go on?

Comment: I've tryed and this code doesn't actually modify my vector structure, also I don't care about the negative integers becouse I have always something greather than 0 in the vector. I'm accepting this answer becouse I'ts the easiest I found to understand, I'm not saying yours is wrong. I'm sorry if I seem so stupid I'm just a newbie. Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't seem stupid, but you need to learn about complexity and what code does. Your teacher also may not agree with you, because in real life, you may encounter often cases where your original contract is X but you end up also handling Y because it's actually more complicated than that.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Sometimes, you don't want **DA BEST** but simply something OK. This is that kind of time.

Comment: Well, there is OK and there is OK. If I pass an interview and the guy does this instead of accumulate, he doesn't get the job. If a guy makes a pull request with this code instead of accumulate, he doesn't pass the review.

Comment: I have to wonder as all these new askers's teachers with the guaranteed `using namespace std;` will accept these modern features.

Comment: @PlayLikeMe10YT • "I'm sorry if I seem so stupid I'm just a newbie."  This stuff is hard.  It's hard in any language.  C++ is harder than many other languages, for good reasons and historical reasons.  And the way that C++ is typically taught makes it seem even more overwhelming and bewildering.  For an alternative way to teach C++ in a kinder, gentler, approachable style, q.v. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Well, I wasn't passing an interview, was I?

Comment: Guys my teacher isn't really a teacher lol, I mean, the only thing he taught was HTML and I already knew that, I'm adventuring all by miself in this new word and I'm just looking for help sometimes, Thanks for all the answers <3